# Is there any example code to nest a D3 visualization within another visualization?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to nest multiple icicle layouts created in D3 within a treemap.

I have only found two questions here that asked about something similar - it was determined that this type of nesting is possible, but I am not able to find an example of how to accomplish this.

Does anyone know how I can go about this, even if it is just steps? Example code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, D3 doesn't care about what container it renders its contents into. That is, you can render into an SVG that covers the whole page, or into a `g` element that is part of something else.

For example, say you start with [this treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582). This is using `div`s for the rectangles. You could append SVGs to these `div`s like so (omitting the code to set the dimensions of the SVG for brevity):

```
var node = div.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
  .data(treemap.nodes)
.enter().append("div")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(position)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("id", ...);
```

So now you have an SVG for each element of the treemap. You can select those individually and append other things to them, e.g. icicle layouts. You would do something like

```
var svg = d3.select("#myId");
// code to render icicle layout into svg
```

Assuming that the width and height of the container are variables that are taken into account when drawing the inner layout, you shouldn't need to change any other code. The only thing to keep in mind is that the containers may be quite small. While the layout will render fine, it may be too small for you to see anything.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Lars, I will try it out. I make use of the full screen, bar a sidebar, so I think it will be ok with size especially as the treemap need only have 16 blocks in total.